# XA Transactions support in MySQL Cluster?

Tags: java, mysql, xa

Does MySQL Cluster supports XA Transactions? I'm using the NDBCLUSTER engine. I have an app which needs to update multiple dbs for a transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote from the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xa-restrictions.html):

> XA transaction support is limited to the InnoDB storage engine.

So the answer is no, XA transactions are not supported in the NDBCLUSTER engine.